# How do I use set /a in freeDOS

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dos

I had recently made my flash drive into a freeDOS environment. I started writing Batch programs for it to make it customized. I made a simple calculator using the `set /a` command like the following example: `set /a ans=%eq%`Where `%eq%` was the math problem. This program worked while using my computer normally, but not with freeDOS.

After I try running this program in freeDOS, it says `Invalid switch. - /a`. So now, in any of my programs, I cannot do mathematical operations. I know that freeDOS uses COMMAND.COM instead of cmd.exe for its command line environment, and I am aware that COMMAND.COM does not have some of the functionality of cmd.exe. Is there some alternate command for mathematical operations? Or can I somehow get cmd.exe installed onto freeDOS?

Comment: `cmd.exe` is a 32bit (or even 64bit) program. DOS and FreeDOS are 16bit operating systems. There is no way you can run a 32bit program on a 16bit OS. `4dos` is a replacement for `command.com` and has much more features: http://www.4dos.info/v4dos.htm#751

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name +1 You should add that as an answer.